# angularjs cant assign ngresource response to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an angular function in coffeescript like so:

```
$scope.personalDone = ->
    user = angular.copy($scope.user)
    saved_user = Api.User.save user
    $scope.classroom.user = saved_user
    $scope.classroom.user_id = saved_user.id
    console.log(saved_user)
    console.log($scope.classroom.user)
    console.log($scope.classroom.user.id)
    console.log($scope.classroom.user_id)
```

And I'm trying to update the $scope.classroom.user_id based on the id of the response, but to no avail. Here are the results of the console logs:

1. Resource {last_name: "Baggins", first_name: "Frodo", id:123}
2. Resource {last_name: "Baggins", first_name: "Frodo", id:123}
3. undefined
4. undefined

How do I assign the Api response to the scope variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `save()` is an **asynchronous** operation, so if you immediately try to use the result, it will fail. What `$resource` is doing in the background is returning an empty object which is later populated with the user that is returned by the server. So if you try to access it immediately, it'll just be an empty object.

However, the object does have a `$promise` property, which allows you to wait until the operation is complete, then do stuff with the new object. Try this:

```
$scope.personalDone = ->
  user = angular.copy($scope.user)
  saved_user = Api.User.save user
  saved_user.$promise.then ->
    $scope.classroom.user = saved_user
    $scope.classroom.user_id = saved_user.id
```

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm!